# DBpedia Jena Query returning null

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I'm just trying to run a small query on DBpedia, the query itself works, see it [here](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%20SELECT%20?label%0D%0A%09%09%09WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Quatre_Bornes%3E%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/country%3E%20?y%20.%0D%0A%09%09%09%20?y%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28?label%29%20=%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D), but I don't why its returning when doing so with Jena, I'm getting null.

```
String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
String queryString = "";
queryString = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> SELECT ?label" +
        "WHERE {" +
        "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Quatre_Bornes> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?y ."+
        "?y rdfs:label ?label ."+ 
        "FILTER (LANG(?label) = 'en')"+
        "}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryEngineHTTP qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest(service, query);
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
for ( ; results.hasNext() ; ) {
    QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;
    System.out.println(soln.getLiteral("label"));
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your answer made sense, and it's useful to others.  (I've this problem arise in other questions, too.)  You should accept your answer so that others know it worked, and to reduce the number of questions without accepted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that is so embarassing, there is space problem in the query:

```
String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
        String queryString = "";
        queryString = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> SELECT ?label " +
            "WHERE {" +
             "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Quatre_Bornes> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?y ."+
             "?y rdfs:label ?label ."+ 
             "FILTER (LANG(?label) = 'en')"+
            "}";
```

Comment: The word WHERE is optional in queries.  Easy solution for strings for queries is not to use it.