# Linked data Jena Eclipse Dbpedia

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I want to linked dbpedia with this code he return me error why..
i change the code with this recente :

```
public class linked2{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String service = "http://dbpedia.org/snorql";
    String queryString = 

            "SELECT DISTINCT ?concept ?label"+
            "WHERE{ "+
                "?concept rdf:type skos:Concept."+ 
                "?concept rdfs:label ?label."+ 
                "?label bif:contains 'samsung'."+ 
                "} ORDER BY DESC(?label) LIMIT 20";
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
//  QueryEngineHTTP qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlservice(service, query);
    QueryEngineHTTP qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest(service, query);
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
    for ( ; results.hasNext() ; ) {
        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;
        System.out.println(soln);
       // System.out.println(soln.getLiteral("label"));
    }
}
```

and also error presented in this picture:

```
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserBase.throwParseException(ParserBase.java:661)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserBase.resolvePName(ParserBase.java:274)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.PrefixedName(SPARQLParser11.java:4888)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.iri(SPARQLParser11.java:4872)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.PathPrimary(SPARQLParser11.java:2922)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.PathElt(SPARQLParser11.java:2852)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.PathEltOrInverse(SPARQLParser11.java:2877)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.PathSequence(SPARQLParser11.java:2830)
```

Comment: I don't see an error in your question…  Where is it?  What is it?

Comment: also, while it's probably not your problem, don't do `lang(?label) = 'en'`.  Language tags are more complicated than that.  Use `langMatches(lang(?label),'en')`.

Comment: I'm not certain, but you also might want to consider using `sparqlService` rather than `createServiceRequest`, since you're not setting any HTTP parameters.

Comment: using [sparqlservice d'ont works]

Comment: in either case, you haven't shown at all what about this code doesn't work.  I can write very similar code, and it worked.

Comment: thank you joshua ,but whene i launch eclipse to run this code , he write error SPARQLParser11.PathSequence 
and i want just to retrive the same concept of samsung or other word 
please help me ,

Answer (score 2):

### Declare your prefixes

Your query is supposed to be

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?concept ?label WHERE {
  ?concept rdf:type skos:Concept.
  ?concept rdfs:label ?label.
  ?label bif:contains 'samsung'.
}
ORDER BY DESC(?label)
LIMIT 20
```

If you put that into [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), you'll see right away:

> **Syntax error:**
>
> Line 2, column 12: Unresolved prefixed name: rdf:type

You probably should have guessed that it was an issue with a prefixed name based on the `resolvePName` in the stacktrace.  At any rate, you'll need to add prefix declarations of the form

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
```

and similarly for the other prefixes that you use (`rdf:` and `bif:`).

### More problems

After you get the prefixes sorted out, you'll find another nasty bug in your query that's already been described in [DBpedia Jena Query returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15663510/1281433).  You really should be using newlines in your query code, e.g.,

```
"select * where {\n" +
"   ...\n"
```

because at the moment, you have

```
"SELECT DISTINCT ?concept ?label"+
"WHERE{ "+
```

which becomes

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?concept ?labelWHERE {
```

Since the `where` in SPARQL queries is optional, you won't get a syntax error, but you don't have a variable in your query called `?labelWHERE`, so you'll always be getting misleading results (the solution doesn't contain a variable `?label`, only `?labelWHERE`).

Comment: i add all prefix but same error

{"prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
    "prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
    "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
    "prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"+
    "prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>"
    + "SELECT DISTINCT ?concept ?label"+
    "WHERE{ "+
     "?concept rdf:type skos:Concept."+ 
     "?concept rdfs:label ?label."+ 
     "?label bif:contains 'samsung'."+ 
     "} ORDER BY DESC(?label) LIMIT 20";}

Comment: Code is impossible to read in comments, and the `http://` from URIs is stripped.  Please update the question with the "edit" link if you have changes to make, or updates to add.  From what I can see, though, you didn't add all the prefixes;  there's no declared prefix for `bif:`, but you use it in `?label bif:contains 'samsung'`.

Comment: thank you for you reponse i change the code and he return 'concept' and 'label' but in empty table ,he contient any data why ..??