# SPARQL query to find the URL of a term in an RDF

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

I want to retrieve all the URLs of a term in an RDF, but I receive none.
Thanks for the help.

The SPARQL query is:

```
String queryString = "PREFIX j.0:<http://myURLList#>" +
                     "PREFIX j.1:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>" +
                       "SELECT ?url" +
                         "WHERE {" +
                             "?term j.0:linkTerm \"respiratory\" ." +
                              "?term j.0:termURL ?url ." +
                         "}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qe =QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
// Output query results 
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
qe.close();
```

Comment: You need to show your data.  What do you expect this to return?  Without seeing your data, we can't say what it should return.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [DBpedia Jena Query returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15663510/1281433).

Comment: I called the wrong PREFIX j.0:<http://myURLList#> when the right one is PREFIX j.0:<http://myURLLists#>. Thank you guys for make me realize that the query was fine.

Comment: `prefix j.0: <myURLLists#>` isn't quite "fine" though, as you won't be constructing absolute URIs, and that means that your results could be rather unpredictable.  (An RDF graph only contains absolute URIs.)

Comment: I am not sure if I have to open a new thread. How could I bind a variable into the query?, I have this line  "?term j.0:linkTerm \"respiratory\" ." + ; I would like to replace \"respiratory\" with a String variable obtained before the query. Thanks.

Comment: You might have a look at [parameterized sparql strings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16739846/1281433).

Comment: The function ParameterizedSparqlString returns a String like: PREFIX j.0:....<respiratory>... .}, I have created a function that returns a String with PREFIX j.0:.... /"respiratory/" ... .} The latter is the format that works in my case.

Comment: ParameterizedSparqlString isn't a function, it's a class.  If you make an instance from, e.g., `select ?x where { ?x rdfs:label ?label }`, and use [setLiteral(String var,String param)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html), to set label `"respiratory"`, then you'll get back `select ?x where { ?x rdfs:label "respiratory" }`.  Jena is documented pretty well, and you'll have much better results if you read the documentation and use the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your java code concatenation is missing new line marks '\n'. This leads to a malformed query in the first case. e.g. instead of "?url WHERE {" your query string contains "?urlWHERE {".

Comment: good catch.  This is a duplicate, actually, of [DBpedia Jena Query returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15663510/1281433).