# SPARQL query using dotNetRDF returns the correct amount of results but with empty values, why?

Tags: c#, sparql, ontology, protege, dotnetrdf

I have tested my SPARQL query on the pizza ontology in protege and the query works fine. Problem is when I attempt to run the same query on the same ontology file using dotNetRDF. The query returns the correct amount of results, but they all seem to be empty.

Can anyone point out what may be the issue here?

Query results using Protege:

[image]

Query results using dotNetRDF:

[image]

Here's my code in C#:

```
OntologyGraph ontGraph = new OntologyGraph();
FileLoader.Load(ontGraph, "PizzaOntology.owl");
ontGraph.BaseUri = null;

#region SPARQL query
SparqlParameterizedString queryString = new SparqlParameterizedString();

queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("rdf", new Uri("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"));
queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("owl", new Uri("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"));
queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("rdfs", new Uri("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"));
queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("xsd", new Uri("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"));
queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("ont", new Uri("http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/pizza.owl#"));

queryString.CommandText = "SELECT ?subject";
queryString.CommandText += "WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ont:PizzaBase }";

SparqlQueryParser parser = new SparqlQueryParser();
SparqlQuery query = parser.ParseFromString(queryString);
#endregion


#region Query Processor
TripleStore store = new TripleStore();
store.Add(ontGraph);

InMemoryDataset ds = new InMemoryDataset(store, true);
ISparqlQueryProcessor processor = new LeviathanQueryProcessor(ds);

object results = processor.ProcessQuery(query);
if (results is SparqlResultSet)
{
    //Print out the Results
    SparqlResultSet rset = (SparqlResultSet)results;
    foreach (SparqlResult result in rset)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Can you post your SafetyOntology.owl?

Comment: @kgu87 I edited the post, showing the same issue with the pizza ontology. Hope it helps

Comment: Your SPARQL query is `SELECT ?subjectWHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ont:PizzaBase }` which is syntactically correct, because the `WHERE` keyword is optional. There are even two results. However, there are no bindings for the `?subjectWHERE` variable.

Comment: @StanislavKralin I see, thank you so much for your comment. Can you point me to the right direction? Maybe an example on how this binding should be done?

Comment: `queryString.CommandText += "  WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ont:PizzaBase }";`. Note the leading space.

Comment: oh I get it now! Thank you so much for the help! really appreciate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DBpedia Jena Query returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663510/dbpedia-jena-query-returning-null)